# Writing to a file but only last line saved

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to copy a text file but when the code finishes executing I only have the last line of text in the file. Obviously the `scanLine()` keeps overwriting the same line but I cant figure out to solve this problem. Any ideas?

```
do{                 
  try{ 
    FileWriter name = new FileWriter("/home/fok/Desktop/out");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(name);
    a=x.nextLine();scanner x grabs next line and sets it string a
    out.write(a);//writes a to file
    out.close();//closees file
  } catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("file writer error");
  } 

} while(x.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple, you are closing and opening the file inside the for loop.

```
 public void readfile(){
   try {           
     FileWriter name = new FileWriter("/home/fok/Desktop/out");
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(name);
      do {                 
        a=x.nextLine();scanner x grabs next line and sets it string a
        out.write(a);//writes a to file
      } while(x.hasNext());
      out.close();//closees file
   } catch (IOException ioe){
      System.out.println("file writer error");
  }
}
```

Comment: but then it cant see the bufferreader out but filewritter and bufferreader must be in try catch so with scope i must have out.write in same block or is there anotherway would appreciate help